# What does the graph of the function $x^{1/x}$ look like near $0$, and does it have a limit there?

Tags: calculus, limits, graphing-functions

Consider the function

$$f(x)=x^{1/x}\tag{1}$$

defined for $x>0$.

We can write this as

$$f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x}\log{x}}$$

Does this function have a limit when $x\to 0$? Maple tells me there isn't.

Also, $\frac{1}{x}\log{x}$ apparently doesn't have a limit when $x\to 0$ either.

My first thought was that the latter would be $-\infty$.

What happens to the function in $(1)$ near $0$?

**EDIT:** as has become clear in the comments, the limits are indeed very simple to compute. My doubts arose because Maple was giving me a weird result, but as per the comments, I needed to tell Maple to compute the limit from above at $0$.

So,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\log{x}}{x}=-\infty$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} x^{1/x}=0$$

Comment: What happens to $e^u$ for $u \to -\infty$?

Comment: As $x\to 0^+$, $\log(x)\to-\infty$ and therefore the limit of $\log(x)/x$ is $-\infty/0^+=-\infty$ and $e^{\log(x)/x}\to 0^+$. Probably Maple fails because it computes the limit with complex variables.

Comment: If what the two comments above say is correct, then maybe it is an issue with the software I am using, though I highly doubt it. I must be missing something or using an incorrect command in Maple or something.

Comment: @evianpring: It could be that Maple only considers the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to a$ if $f$ is defined in a punctured neighbourhood of $a$. Your function is not defined for negative reals, and so there is no $r>0$ such that $f$ is defined on $(-r,r)\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @evianpring Try limit(x^(1/x),x=0,right), it should work!

Comment: @RobertZ Indeed you are correct, it does work. $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} x^{1/x}=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log{x}}{x}=-\infty$. All is as it should be, and the issue was simply a software usage mistake.